# I'm trying to make a point system to determine the winner between 4 players

Tags: c#, system, points, playing-cards

I'm trying to add points into count by verifying the string value but since .equal and .contains only works with string, i have no idea how to  count points. Am i supposed to make my own .equal method for type variable card? The requirement is that the number must have a spades/heart/diamond/club value.

```
//card class...
class Card
{
    public string s;
    public string f;

    public Card (string sC, string fC)
    {

        s = sC;
        f = fC;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return f + s;
    }
}

//Deck class....

string[] cards = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                              "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K",
                              "A"};
//spades, diamond , club, heart. not necessarily in the same order

string[] type = { "\x2660", "\x2666", "\x2665", "\x2663" };

deck = new Card[52];
random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; i++)
{
    deck[i] = new Card(cards[i % 13], type[i / 13]);
}

//output is spades of 2

Console.WriteLine(Deck[0]);

void Shuffle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.Length; top++)
    {
        int j = random.Next(52);
        Card temp = playDeck[i];
        playDeck[i] = playDeck[j];
        playDeck[j] = temp;
    }
}
Card passCards()
{
    if (currentCard < deck.Length)
    {
        return deck[currentCard++];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}


// Method I'm trying to make

int count =0;

int countPoints()
{
    for(int i = currentCard; i < deck.Length; i++)
    {
        if (deck[currentCard].Equals("1"))
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    return count
}

//main...
Console.WriteLine("playername" + ...13 cards.. + Total points : " + deck.countPoints());
```

Comment: The string value of what? You can override `ToString()` on any class to make it return whatever you want. You can also compare your `s` and `f` fields directly (these should really be named better and be implemented as properties). It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps you could also use some more descriptive names than `s`, `f`, `sC`, `fC` so your code is more readable...

Comment: yes i didnt want to post my entire code.

Comment: You don't have to post the entire code, just post ***compileable*** code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to map string values to points?

Comment: Yes. the major code is posted. i want a out put something like this playername 13 cards Total points :. but i need the type of card in front of the card so spades of 4. but using the unicode

Comment: Shouldn't `cards` be a `Card[]` or a `List<Card>`?

Comment: I don't understand how many points a card would be worth based on your code

Comment: So don't use strings. Represent cards as numbers, and only convert to strings for input and output.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to store the card `Name` property as an `enum`, where the position of each name correlates to the card's value (at least for the numbered cards). For example:

```
// Start the Ace with value 1, the rest are automatically one greater than the previous
public enum CardName
{
    Ace = 1, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King
}
```

This makes calculating the score for a specific name pretty easy. If the value is `1` then return `11` (assuming Aces are 11), if it's greater than `9`, then return `10` (assuming face cards are 10), otherwise return the value:

```
public int Value
{
    get
    {
        var value = (int) Name;
        return value == 1 ? 11 : value > 9 ? 10 : value;
    }
}
```

And now, if we have a `List<card> hand`, we can get the sum of the cards in the hand by doing something like:

```
int total = hand.Sum(card => card.Value);
```

---

For completeness, here's a little sample of a `Card` class, a `Deck` class (which is a fancy wrapper around a `List<Card>`), and an example usage of them to show how you can get the sum of a player's hand:

```
public enum Suit { Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds, Spades}

public enum CardName
{
    Ace = 1, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King
}

public class Card
{ 
    public Suit Suit { get; }
    public CardName Name { get; }

    public int Value => (int) Name == 1 ? 11 : (int) Name > 9 ? 10 : (int) Name;

    public Card(CardName name, Suit suit)
    {
        Name = name;
        Suit = suit;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} of {Suit}";
    }
}

public class Deck
{
    private readonly List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
    private readonly Random random = new Random();

    public int Count => cards.Count;

    public static Deck GetStandardDeck(bool shuffled)
    {
        var deck = new Deck();
        deck.ResetToFullDeck();
        if (shuffled) deck.Shuffle();
        return deck;
    }

    public void Add(Card card)
    {
        cards.Add(card);
    }

    public bool Contains(Card card)
    {
        return cards.Contains(card);
    }

    public bool Remove(Card card)
    {
        return cards.Remove(card);
    }

    public int Sum => cards.Sum(card => card.Value);

    public Card DrawNext()
    {
        var card = cards.FirstOrDefault();
        if (card != null) cards.RemoveAt(0);
        return card;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        cards.Clear();
    }

    public void ResetToFullDeck()
    {
        cards.Clear();

        // Populate our deck with 52 cards
        foreach (Suit suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
        {
            foreach (CardName name in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CardName)))
            {
                cards.Add(new Card(name, suit));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        var thisIndex = cards.Count;

        while (thisIndex-- > 1)
        {
            var otherIndex = random.Next(thisIndex + 1);
            if (thisIndex == otherIndex) continue;

            var temp = cards[otherIndex];
            cards[otherIndex] = cards[thisIndex];
            cards[thisIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var deck = Deck.GetStandardDeck(true);
        var playerHand = new Deck();
        var computerHand = new Deck();

        Console.WriteLine("Each of us will draw 5 cards. " +
            "The one with the highest total wins.");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            GetKeyFromUser($"\nPress any key to start round {i + 1}");

            var card = deck.DrawNext();
            Console.WriteLine($"\nYou drew a {card}");
            playerHand.Add(card);

            card = deck.DrawNext();
            Console.WriteLine($"I drew a {card}");
            computerHand.Add(card);
        }

        while (playerHand.Sum == computerHand.Sum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nOur hands have the same value! Draw another...");

            var card = deck.DrawNext();
            Console.WriteLine($"\nYou drew a {card}");
            playerHand.Add(card);

            card = deck.DrawNext();
            Console.WriteLine($"I drew a {card}");
            computerHand.Add(card);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"\nYour total is: {playerHand.Sum}");
        Console.WriteLine($"My total is: {computerHand.Sum}\n");

        Console.WriteLine(playerHand.Sum > computerHand.Sum
            ? "Congratulations, you're the winner!"
            : "I won this round, better luck next time!");

        GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
    }

    private static ConsoleKeyInfo GetKeyFromUser(string prompt)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        var key = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();
        return key;
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]